# Creating new Logger

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to create a new logger for my plugin. However it does not write any content to the file. The logging events provide no errors. If I do not supply a handler I can get all the log events in the console.

It seems the logger is handling the file, as it creates a `chatlog.log.lck` file.

Subsequently, is there a way to also log what is logged to my "new" logger, to the console as well?

```
private void setupLogger() {

    logger = Logger.getLogger("WeChat");

    File lf = new File(getDataFolder() + File.separator + "logs");

    if (!(lf.exists())){
        lf.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(getDataFolder() + File.separator + "logs" + File.separator + "chatlog.log", true);
        SimpleFormatter fmt = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(fmt);
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Again I can get input in the console, just no the file

```
[23:48:24 INFO]: [WeChat] [Channel TheLounge] WASasquatch: Hello everyone!?
[23:48:30 INFO]: [WeChat] [Channel TheLounge] WASasquatch: Test test
[23:48:36 INFO]: [WeChat] [Channel TheLounge] WASasquatch: This in the log file now?
```

Comment: Try setting the log level on `fh`. Maybe it is too high to print anything.

Comment: @AxelH I do not understand what you mean? @Thilo I am using `logger.info()` and `logger.warning()` which both present their own logging levels, one which is low.

Comment: `logger.info("foo");` after the try catch did what was expected .. this is not reproducible. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a constructor in [`FileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) to set the file as append or not. (and to set a rolling file system if needed, same constructor without the rolling system exist).

```
public FileHandler(String pattern,
       int limit,
       int count,
       boolean append)
        throws IOException,
               SecurityException
```

Defined the level for this handler if needed, `defaults to Level.ALL`

Here is a quick sample :

```
public class Main {

    static Logger logger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("Main");
        FileHandler fh;

        File lf = new File("data" + File.separator + "logs" + File.separator + "chatlog.log");

        if (!(lf.getParentFile().exists())){
            lf.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }


        try {
            fh = new FileHandler(lf.getCanonicalPath(), 8096, 1, true);
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            SimpleFormatter fmt = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(fmt);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logger.info("foo");
        logger.info("bar");
    }
}
```

Note the update to use the `File` instance path instead of recreate the String.

I use an none existant folder. Launch the process twice and as expected, the file as the line for both execution.

Comment: This is causing Spigot to hang at enabling my plugin. Changed code: https://pastebin.com/pFB38iTN

Comment: Eventually ends in a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` on the FileHandler constructor. https://pastebin.com/0st6JgJJ

Comment: Ok. So I lowered the limit all the way down to 1mb and it was able to start the server, but this doesn't work. It just outputs to the console now and creates a `chatlog.log.0` and `chatlog.log.0.lck` file and doesn't write to it, or `chatlog.log`

Comment: See my updated post. I get no double entries in my console, just single entries, and nothing in the file.

Comment: @JordanSasquatchMan The double entry is because of the consoleHandler I used (not necessery at all). But if I simply add `logger.info("foo");` at the end of your code, I get a file with a content and the console output. Please provide a [mcve] to reproduce this

Comment: It must be conflicting with me method to retrieve the logger which is `getLogger()` in the same method. Going to test renaming it.

Comment: Yes it was conflicting. I had to cast to my Main. Somehow it was able to use the name from my new logger, but was retrieving Bukkit's logger.

Comment: @JordanSasquatchMan Check your imports, you probably used the wrong one. This is the risk to use already used Class name, permitted but still risky

Comment: It was the method name `getLogger()` which is present in JavaPlugin as well as my main WeChat. I renamed it. The issue now is suddenly, now that it works, it ignores the name "WeChat" and prints the **entire** package, and method it was used in. `May 05, 2017 12:07:07 AM wa.was.wechat.events.Commands onCommand
INFO: test` So i no longer get `[WeChat] test` in console but just `test`